# Overriding Android Hardware buttons

Tags: android, overriding, android-hardware

I just got with an idea and I got a question.

Can I override android phones' power button functions?

For example, turning an flash by pressing the power button.

Is it possible?

Thx.

Comment: @user2413927 oh it really is ;) didn't cheched it..

Comment: Then you can mark my answer as a sure :D